# Autoclose datepicker in mobile view

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, ionic-framework

I am unable to autoclose the datepicker in mobile view.Because we don't use mouse in mobile view

```
$('#dateofbirth').mouseover(function (){
    $('#dateofbirth').show();
});
$("#datofbirth").mouseout(function(){
    $('#dateofbirth').hide();
});
```

Comment: *autoclose* after select?

Comment: I think you need to handle this with a click on mobile. I think it would help if you show the markup.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/taditdash/rU5Nc/

Comment: If we not the select the date it should be close.but it is still open and when we press browser back button the same datepicker is reflecting.so,if select it should be display if not it should disable

Comment: I am using Ionic.so,javascript and jquery will not work